# Windows user home folder in C (MinGW)

Tags: c, windows, mingw, msys

I'm trying to port an application written in C from linux to windows.

At the moment I'm done fixing the 'hard' parts like [missing posix features](http://svn.etv.cx/wsvn/swarmtv/?op=comp&compare[]=/branches/swarmtv-win32@270&compare[]=/branches/swarmtv-win32@271&manualorder=1&ignorews=0) and the like.

The application compiles, links and works on Windows now (except for the fork() stuff which will be replaced with windows service code later).

The only problem I'm having now is that within the MSYS shell it all works (this maps unix paths for me).

Outside of the MSYS shell it won't work because ~ is not available.

I'm looking for the best way to set the windows user home within my #ifdef stuff.

I read about `%USERPROFILE%` somewhere but that doesn't seem to [work](http://svn.etv.cx/wsvn/swarmtv/?op=comp&compare[]=/branches/swarmtv-win32@271&compare[]=/branches/swarmtv-win32@272).

Comment: `%USERPROFILE%` should be right, at least on Windows 7. It may vary on other OSs.

Comment: sound strange because the env variable USERPROFILE should contain the home folder.

Comment: `%USERPROFILE%` works fine, but from a program you should use `SHGetFolderLocation` or one of its friends. If you can't get `%USERPROFILE%` to work then you are doing it wrong.

Comment: @the JinX It sounds to me like you don't know much about Windows and are ranting and raving about Windows when in fact you should concentrate on bringing your own knowledge of this particular platform up to scratch.

Comment: True, can you link me to some good POSIX to Window API documentation?

Comment: @the JinX No, I know nothing about POSIX. Did you know that Windows is POSIX compliant? Not that that really means a lot!

Comment: It's [Windows SUA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Services_for_UNIX) that is POSIX compliant - regular Windows isn't, and doesn't try to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`SHGetKnownFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (Vista+) or `SHGetFolderPath` depending on your Windows version.

Comment: Will try these.
Lets hope I don't need MSVC for this . .

Comment: Looking at the MSDN I didn't see the 'which headers' part first so was a bit confused, that lead me to think it wouldn't quite work with MinGW.

Comment: THanks!
These got me to some good examples of how to replace one character with 10+ lines of code.

Yet another hurdle taken .. thanks to all involved .. even the person downvoting my question for no good reason.

Comment: @the JinX Nobody likes it if you use vulgar cuss words. If you can't abide by that then you'd be better off posting on a forum that welcomes such language. Is it so hard to try and fit in? Especially when you are asking for help.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use the SHGetFolderLocation API:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762180%28VS.85%29.aspx
well not enought, you should even retrieve the ID of the user folder, but by starting at the doc location above you should have all what you neeed. 
This should works on any windows version.